# Роспись и подпись

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Мой вопрос — в [цитате](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=265698) с Грамоты (орфография и пунктуация авторские):

> **Вопрос № 265698**
>
> С середины прошлого века, во времена СССР, был убежден, что правильно говорить и писать - "поставить подпись", "довести под расписку", "подпись в получении". В официальных документах - например, приказах министров, встречались только такие выражения.
>
> В разговорной речи нередко проскальзывали выражения "под роспись", "роспись в получении". Терпеливо доказывал, что "роспись" - это художественная роспись фресок в церквах, художественная роспись на шкатулках, матрешках, посуде, металле, керамике и т.д.
>
> В последнее десятилетие все чаще стали встречаться "под роспись" в официальной документации современной России, особенное недоумение вызвало законодательное внесение изменений в Трудовой Кодекс, где прямо закреплены понятия "под роспись".
>
> Вопрос: с чем это связано? Почему на законодательном уровне стали применяться безграмотные выражения?
>
> Сергей Г
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Значения слов подпись и роспись не изменились, роспись в значении 'подпись' по-прежнему ошибка. Причины частотности этой ошибки те же, что и в ситуации надеть – одеть: разница в значении этих похожих по звучанию слов для многих неочевидна. К тому же носителей языка окончательно запутывает глагол расписаться. Так и оказалась эта ошибка в Трудовом кодексе.

Вообще-то это давнишний спор... Мне ответ Справки на Грамоте кажется неполным. И даже неубедительным.

Что думаете? Каково значение обоих слов в современном языке?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Вот и словари начали фиксировать то, что в языке существует давно. Вспоминаю себя: до какого-то момента я не знала о словах роспись и подпись всего того, что Вы процитировали с "Грамоты". Нам было лет по 12-14 (или меньше?), когда мы с девчонками придумывали "роспись" - "фамилию с закорючками", которую мы будем ставить в каком-либо документе.  Мы придумывали ее на листочке бумаги, показывали друг другу - разве можно сказать, что это была подпись? Это была именно "роспись", как бы заготовка для подписи. Ведь **под**пись - это то, что ставят **под** документом. Так подсказывало мне мое "языковое чутьё". Потом уже оказалось, что это не так.

В дополнение к первому ответу (с просторов Интернета):
«Роспись» — термин, закрепленный официальным стандартом.

ГОСТ Р 51141-98 «Делопроизводство и архивное дело. Термины и определения» (http://www.directum.ru/340614.aspx) дает следующее определение:

Подпись: Реквизит документа, представляющий собой собственноручную роспись полномочного должностного лица

Таким образом, официально: начирканная каракуля — это именно роспись, а подпись — реквизит документа, эту каракулю содержащий.

Comment: >>>начирканная каракуля — это именно роспись, а подпись — реквизит документа, эту каракулю содержащий.  

Во! Вот это именно та формулировка, под которой я бы подписался не задумываясь.  
Другими словами:  
Подпись - юридический реквизит документа,
Роспись - его графическое воплощение.

Comment: Гораздо понятнее, чем у Т. Ефремовой

Comment: А что тогда такое "Реквизит документа"?

Answer (score 5):

Судя по *словарю Т. Ефремовой*, второй из двух омонимов слова *роспись* сейчас является    практически полным синонимом слова *подпись*:

**Подпись**:

1. Действие по гл. подписать I (от подписывать I 1.)
2. Надпись на чем-либо, под чем-либо.
3. Собственноручно написанная фамилия под текстом, рисунком и т.п. в подтверждение своего
   авторства или согласия с чем-либо.

**Роспись**:

I 1. Процесс действия по гл. расписывать II 1.
2. Результат такого действия; покрытие какой-либо поверхности - стен, потолка и т.п. -   рисунком или какими-либо композициями.
3. Сюжетные изображения и орнаменты, создаваемые средствами декоративной живописи на   различных частях архитектурных сооружений и на изделиях декоративно-прикладного искусства.

II 1. Процесс действия по гл. расписываться.  
2. Результат такого действия; чья-либо собственноручная подпись на документе,    удостоверяющая что-либо.
3. Текст с чьей-либо подписью, свидетельствующий о чем-либо или удостоверяющий что-либо.

Comment: Спасибо, только до синонимии здесь ещё ой как далеко.

Comment: Ну почему же далеко? Роспись II в приведенной цитате - это синоним подписи. Вы вчитайтесь в определения: одно и то же описывается.

Comment: Вчитываюсь. Синонимии не вижу. Даже паронимия весьма условная.
Вы, возможно, исходите из синонимичности глаголов "подписаться" и "расписаться", но не это так.

Comment: Исхожу из процитированных значений и значения слова "синонимы".

Comment: Тогда вопрос закрыт. Синонимичности нет.