# Расписаться, но подпись

Tags: словообразование

Роспись — это художественное оформление чего-либо, подпись — личный автограф человека. Но при этом почему-то человека просят расписаться в документе, а не подписаться. Тогда почему то, что он нарисует, будет подписью, а не росписью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если строго по вопросу "As Is" (как он задан), то подобная логика просто не работает.
Не всегда название **результата** действия совпадает с названием самого действия. "Роспись" - это процесс создания подписи (отсюда "дать под роспись"), графическое воплощение подписи, но никак не сама подпись как юридически значимое действие или реквизит.

А если по сути, то повтор. Посмотрите здесь. Там довольно много текста, цитировать не хочу.

[Роспись и подпись](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6295)