# Подпишитесь или распишитесь?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, глаголы, деловой-язык

В [тесте](http://pushkininstitute.ru/exam/quizzes/55/user_quizzes/3337) на уровень владения русским языком как иностранным наткнулся на такой вопрос:

> **Пожалуйста, … в квитанции, что вы получили заказанные книги.**
>
> - подпишитесь
> - запишитесь
> - впишитесь
> - распишитесь

Тут любой русский человек выберет ***распишитесь*,** и тест примет этот ответ за правильный. Но вот наш преподаватель по корреспонденции утверждает, что, когда дело касается бумаг, нужно говорить ***подписаться*,** а не ***расписаться*.**

В связи с этим вопрос: допустимо ли использование глагола ***расписаться*** в значении ***поставить подпись*** в повседневной речи, в деловой речи?

Comment: Расписаться можно, к примеру, в собственном бессилии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, в примере теста правильный выбор такой. Но на то и синонимы, чтобы выбирать их сообразно ситуации, а не по настроению, вкусу или какой привычнее. Думаю, что преподаватель ваш говорит о другой ситуации и различает эти два варианта примерно так:

**расписаться** - поставить подпись **на** чём-л (в знак чего-либо, как образец подписи, для удостоверения факта получения/ознакомления, как автограф и т.п.) здесь акцент на физическом действии, вне связи с расположением подписи относительно текста (это может быть напр. "там, где галочка")

**подписаться** **под** чем-л., на что-л. (или переходный глагол **подписать** что-л.) - поставить подпись **под** своим или общим текстом, на живописном полотне и пр.; это делается "под" текстовым или иным материалом, за который человек берёт ответственность или на который обозначает своё авторство. Частный случай "ответственности" - **подписаться на** какое-либо издание (подпись как бы ставится под документом, которым оформляется намерение человека получать или выкупать печатные материалы)

Соответственно, "расписаться" можно на документе, составленном *не от вашего имени*, в знак удостоверения факта ознакомления с ним (приказ о повышении), факта получения чего-либо (квитанция) и т. д.  В противном случае документ (заявление, показания, служебная записка) *подписывают* или под ним *подписываются* (особенно если текст составлен самим человеком).

Answer (score 2):

Несколько раз уже отвечали.

[Роспись и подпись](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/)
(тут и обсуждение есть с ответами.)

[Расписаться, но подпись](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21645)

А если конкретно на вопрос, то преподаватель прав, если речь касается автора письма. Письмо или документ подписывают, расписываясь. А технический работник, секретарь, исполнитель ставит подпись, расписывается, но вряд ли подписывается. Это относится и к квитанции.

Comment: Не совсем так. Это смотря какой техработник. Если высокопоставленный, то он иногда, расписывается, но при этом *визирует*, а не расписывается. Но в целом согласен. Вы на правильном пути..

Answer (score 1):

Ваш преподаватель путает "расписаться" и "роспись" (в значении "подпись"). Роспись – разговорное слово. А в документах расписываются, либо подписывают их.

Comment: Ага. Все разговорные – ненормальные. Кто тут запутался-то?

Comment: Меньше на себя, любимого внимания обращайте. Мне интересны не вы, а Ваши недоразумения. А на личности переходить - это к Сержу.

Comment: Я смотрю,вы так раздухарились, что уже и с чтением и пониманием прочитанного у вас большие проблемы. Ну-ка, еще раз, сосредоточьтесь: "роспись" – слово нормальное, в любом словаре есть. Но – разговорное. Ага?

Comment: Не агу, а "агу". Сосредоточтесь (С). У меня было  *"Нормальное слово, в любом словаре есть. Вы запутались в значениях"*, остальное - Ваши домыслы. Могу добавить: **Никакое оно не разговорное**. Это тоже я сказал.

Comment: >> *Никакое оно не разговорное. 
>> Это тоже я сказал*

Ну и что? Кого-то интересует мнение  behemothus'а, которое расходится с общепринятым?

Comment: И много вы приняли, чтобы свое мнение называть общим? Я говорю для тех, кого моё мнение интересует, а вот считать таковых предоставляю Вам. Что же касается общепринятых мнений, то именно его я и привел. ***Слово не является разговорным, это нормальное общелитературное слово. Вы запутались в значениях.*** Все. Остальное можете написать себе на лбу и так доказывать всем, что Ваша манера передергивать - это очень культурно.

Comment: В словари не пробовали смотреть? Хоть иногда... Или сами себе словарь?

Comment: Я-то пробовал. И Вам советовал. А Вы решили за свой базар не отвечать. Повторяю, в словарях слово не считается разговорным. Вы запутались в значениях.

Comment: Не хотелось тыкать носом, но придется...

РОСПИСЬ, -и; ж. 1. к Расписать - расписывать (3 зн.). Приступить к росписи Владимирского собора. 2. Декоративная живопись на стенах, потолках зданий и предметах быта. Художественная р. Античная р. сосудов. Стены храма покрыты росписью. 3. Письменный перечень, список чего-л. Р. доходов и расходов. Р. имущества. **4. Разг. =Подпись**. Посмотрите, это ваша р.? Не хватает чьей-л. росписи.