# "Роспись в получении" или "подпись в получении"

Tags: выбор-слов, словосочетания

Вариация вопроса, ставшего классикой, знаю.
Но все же, если согласиться с тем, что "подпись" - это, грубо говоря, результат "росписи" (см. [Роспись и подпись](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)), какое же все-таки следует выбрать слово в словосочетании "Роспись/подпись в получении ключа"?

Comment: Подпись, которую можно заменить "распиской".

Comment: Хотите сказать, "подпись в получении" либо "расписка в получении"?

Comment: Повтор. Вопрос не раз звучал и имеет ответы.  http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: Автор вопроса сам дал эту ссылку; в такой форме вопрос не ставился.

Comment: Да, так и думаю. Но так как проговорила в уме уже много раз обе фразы, то они уже у меня затуманились - и нужен холодный взгляд на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

В Нацкорпусе 12 примеров вида "**расписка в получении**", и нет ни росписи, ни подписи в получении, например: "И почему никого не удивило, что **расписка в получении** денег за туробслуживание была написана аж за полгода".  Таким образом, можно сделать вывод **о несочетаемости слов в приведенных выражениях**.

**Из словаря:**

**РАСПИСКА,**  1. к Расписать - расписывать (1-3 зн.). Р. счетов по книгам. Р. стен фресками. **2. =Подпись (2 зн.)**. Предоставить ведомость с расписками получателей. Без расписки перевод не выдадут. 3. **Документ с подписью, подтверждающий получение чего-л.** Долговая р. Дать, предъявить расписку кому-л. Получить расписку от кого-л. Р. в получении ссуды.

**РОСПИСЬ**, -и; ж. 1. к Расписать - расписывать (3 зн.).  2. Декоративная живопись   3. Письменный перечень, список чего-л. Р. доходов и расходов. Р. имущества. 4. **Разг. =Подпись.** Посмотрите, это ваша р.?

**ПОДПИСЬ,** -и; ж. 1. к Подписать (1-2 зн.). Бумаги для подписи. Отправить документы на п. **2. Фамилия, собственноручно поставленная под чем-л. (под каким-л. текстом, рисунком,**

Answer (score 0):

Содержание или результат действия "*расписаться в получении*" нельзя выразить словами "подпись в получении": подпись ставят в документе или под документом (текстом), и напрямую словом "подпись" (где, под чем) не сослаться на его содержание - не та сочетаемость. Поэтому, если стоит выбор между двумя предложенными вариантами, лучше выбрать меньшее из зол (рискуя, что где-то сказанное назовут "разговорным выражением"): поставив свою подпись (расписавшись) в ведомости, оставляют *роспись в получении*. И это не "расписка" (подписанный текст от своего имени).