# Подписи или росписи?

Tags: словосочетания, паронимы

Что будет правильнее использовать в предложении "подписи" или "росписи":

> Пришел главбух, велел всем поставить в ведомости (подписи, росписи) и получить деньги.

Мне кажется, правильным вариантом будет - подписи, но я не знаю почему. Можете помочь с объяснением? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Этот вопрос [уже был](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c).

Comment: @grizzly, благодарю, изначально не нашел этот вопрос.